# Laravel pagination page 2 loses the data

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, request

When i fill my search and post it, it gets the data and returns it.
In this query i use ->paginate(50);

```
$products = Product7Days::where('omschrijving', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->omschrijving.'%')
                                    ->where('artikelnummer', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->artikelnummer.'%')
                                    ->whereIn('relatienummer', $leverancierenArray)
                                    ->whereIn('omzetgroep', $omzetgroepenArray)
                                    ->whereIn('btwcode', $BTWArray)
                                    ->whereBetween('prijs', [$prijsVan, $prijsTot])
                                    ->where('totaalaantal', '>=', $aantalVan)
                                    ->where('totaalaantal', '<=', $aantalTot)
                                    ->paginate(50);
```

My routes

```
Route::get('/artikelen', 'ProductController@index')->name('artikelen');

Route::post('/artikelen', 'ProductController@search')->name('artikelen.search');
```

[The pagination on the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZ2aA.png)

So that all works, but when i go to the second page, for some reason no result is there

when i search, it goes to this page
http://172.16.0.51:8000/artikelen

and when i click on page 2 the link is
http://172.16.0.51:8000/artikelen?page=2
But no data

Blade file

```
@if (isset($products))
                    <table class="table table-striped table-responsive-xl">
                        <thead class="thead-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Artikelnummer</th>
                                <th>Omschrijving</th>
                                <th>Prijs</th>
                                <th>Totaal <br> verkocht</th>
                                <th>Totaal <br> omzet</th>
                                @foreach ($filialen as $filiaal)
                                @if ($filiaal !== 6)
                                <th>aantal. <br>F{{$filiaal}}</th>
                                <th>voorr. <br>F{{$filiaal}}</th>
                                @else
                                <th>voorr. <br>F{{$filiaal}}</th>
                                @endif
                                @endforeach
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach ($products as $product)
                            <tr>
                                <th>{{ $product->artikelnummer}}</th>
                                <th>{{ $product->omschrijving}}</th>
                                <th>{{ $product->prijs}}</th>
                                <th>{{ $product->totaalaantal}}</th>
                                <th class="text-right">{{ round($product->totaalaantal * $product->prijs, 1) }}</th>
                                @foreach ($filialen as $filiaal)
                                @if ($filiaal !== 6)
                                <th class="text-right">{{ $product["aantalF".$filiaal] }}</th>
                                <th class="text-right">{{ $product["voorraadF".$filiaal] }}</th>
                                @else
                                <th>{{ $product->voorraadF6 }}</th>
                                @endif
                                @endforeach
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    {{ $products->links() }}
                    @endif
```

The isset() returns false...

I am pretty sure when i click page 2 the data is getting lost but then would my question be how to i give that data through

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Pagination with Get request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312582/laravel-pagination-with-get-request)

Comment: @WahyuKristianto there isnt much to see, just on top you have all the question im asking for and under that should be the foreach wil all the data from page 2

Comment: Is it possible to access `articleen` route without using GET parameters? Something like `?omschrijving=xxx&artikelnummer=xxx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent default behavior of pagination links in Laravel, this solotion works for search urls like `http://172.16.0.51:8000/search?property1=x&property2=y`

```
$(document).on('click', '.pagination li a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).attr('href')) {
        var queryString = '';
        var allQueries = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        if(allQueries[0].split('=').length >1){
            for (var i = 0; i < allQueries.length; i++) {
                var hash = allQueries[i].split('=');
                if (hash[0] !== 'page') {
                    queryString += '&' + hash[0] + '=' + hash[1];
                }
            }
        }
        window.location.replace($(this).attr('href') + queryString);
    }
});
```

Comment: but this doesnt help me? because my link is /artikelen?page=2

Comment: why don't you try ?

Comment: i tried, the link stayed the same and no result given. maybe im doing it wrong?\

Comment: use `paginate()` in search result instead of `get()`  so they both make pagination links, when clicking links it goes to the proper route, if it has query sting goes to search function otherwise to other function

Comment: Wait im confused, im not using get()?

Comment: Ok soo i got this to work, with ur jquery script, and now it works fine, but the only thing is, when i search to a big search my laravel crashes. because of my URL wich gets to long